# Install Virtualbox in WSL Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to have access to Virtualbox from within the WSL, I have tried to `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` but I end up with the following error:

```
WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
     Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate
     headers, most likely linux-headers-3.4.0+.

     You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
```

4.3.36_Ubuntur105129

Comment: why? Install the Windows version of virtualbox

Comment: You can't access windows binaries from the bash terminal. If you know a way please let me know.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do this and need to access Virtualbox via bash.

Comment: Vagrant uses virtualbox via bash. That's one reason you would need it

Comment: Correct, I want to control my virtualboxes via the vagrant cli tool.

Comment: I understand why you would like this to work :-) however I am also having issues getting this to work -- I have until now used a virtualbox on windows with a ubuntu and inside a virtualbox vagrant setup -- it is a bit problematic, however it is possible

Answer (score 10):

Vagrant is now capable of detecting that it is running on WSL.
How to configure Windows and WSL to enable this feature is described on [Vagrant website](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html)
They claim it's an advanced feature but the configuration seems quite straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that will not work (at least for now), as explained here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/549